# ¿Por que mi funcion no es reconocida?

Tags: javascript

Hola estoy aprendiendo javascript y quisiera saber por que me sale un error si pongo la funcion registro del prototipo como la puse en el codigo mostrado, pero si la pongo abajo de esta linea: **Estudiante.prototype.constructor = Estudiante;**    si la reconoce, logre hacer que funcionara poniendola debajo de esa linea pero quisiera saber por que funciona ahi y arriba no.

(Espero y me haya hecho entender)

```js
        function Persona (nombre,edad,genero) {

            this.nombre = nombre;

            this.edad = edad;

            this.genero = genero;
        }

        Persona.prototype.obtDetalles = function () {

            for(const propiedad in this) {
                console.log(this[propiedad]);
            }

        }


        const Alexis = new Persona("Alexis", 17,"Masculino");

        console.log(Alexis);


        

        function Estudiante (nombre,edad,genero,curso,grupo) {
            this.super = Persona;
            this.super(nombre,edad,genero);

            this.curso = curso;
            this.grupo = grupo;
            
        }

        Estudiante.prototype.registro = function () {
            
            console.log("Te has registrado");

        }

        Estudiante.prototype = new Persona();   

        Estudiante.prototype.constructor = Estudiante;



        const Daniel = new Estudiante("Daniel", 17, "Masculino", "Matematicas", "6AMM");

        
        console.log(Daniel.registro);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

en primera instancia, veo que estas algo confundido con respecto a los prototipos y a los constructores de una clase, de por si lo que haces con las funciones esta mal, pues lo que estas haciendo es **redundante**.

Y aqui te van unos puntos del porque:

- Hacer: `Estudiante.prototype.constructor = Estudiante;` es redundante, pues no necesitas definir un constructor explicitamente si solo quieres crear una clase.

Checa este ejemplo:

```js
function Carro(peso){
  this.peso = peso;
}

const carro = new Carro(10);
const carro2 = new Carro(1000);

console.log(carro.peso);
```

Como vemos, si estas usando funciones **NO** necesitas un constructor para poder usar la palabra reservada **new** por esta razon es redundante.

- Esta linea de aqui: `Estudiante.prototype = new Persona();` no tiene sentido, pues estas asignandole al prototipo de estudiante una nueva instancia, lo cual como digo no tiene sentido, pues las clases se supone que son **plantillas**, en este caso yo te recomendaria que **JAMAS** hagas algo asi.
- La linea `this.super = Persona;` parece ser una simulacion de herencia, sin embargo la palabra reservada `super` no puede usarse de la forma en la que lo estas haciendo, ya que tu estas creando una propiedad llamada `super` y luego quieres usarla como metodo, lo cual obviamente te va a dar un **error** y aparte no cumplira su funcion, pues enrealidad nunca estas extendiendo de una clase padre asociada.
- Con respecto a tu pregunta principal, **¿Por que mi funcion no es reconocida?**, es simplemente por el hecho de que **los prototipos solamente se pueden asignar despues de que el objeto haya sido definido**, no recuerdo exactamente como se le llama a esta situación donde en este caso si importa el orden, sin embargo es simplemente una cuestion de orden, es decir, imagina que es como cocinar, tu no puedes cocinar un huevo si primero no tienes a mano y listo la paila para cocinar el huevo.

De todas maneras y por buenas practicas te recomiendo que uses las clases de `ES6`, pues estas ya contienen justo todo lo que intentas realizar, te doy un ejemplo muy sencillo de las clases en `ES6`:

```js
class Vehiculo{

  constructor(tipo, peso, anchura, altura){
    this.tipo = tipo;
    this.peso = peso;
    this.anchura = anchura;
    this.altura = altura;
  }
  
  manejar(){
    console.log(`Estas manejando un: ${this.tipo}`);
  }

}

class Camion extends Vehiculo{

  constructor(tipo, peso, anchura, altura){
    super(tipo, peso, anchura, altura);
  }

}

class Avion extends Vehiculo{

  constructor(tipo, peso, anchura, altura, velocidad){
    super(tipo, peso, anchura, altura);
    this.velocidad = velocidad;
  }
  
  volar(){
    console.log(`El avion esta volando a ${this.velocidad} KM/H`);
  }

}

Vehiculo.prototype.tanquear = function(){
  console.log("El vehiculo se esta tanqueando!!");
}

const camion = new Camion("Camion", 2200, 2.5, 3.2);
const avion = new Avion("Avion", 20000, 6, 100, 980);

//Informacion del camion
camion.manejar();
//Informacion del avion
avion.manejar();
avion.volar();
//Ejecucion de la funcion tanquear seteada en el prototype de Vehiculo
camion.tanquear();
avion.tanquear();
```

Como vemos usar clases de `ES6` tiene bastantes ventajas, algunas de ellas son que ya tienen construido en su arquitectura el mecanismo para extender o heredar de otras clases superiores, ademas de poder utilizar **getters** y **setters** y organizar de mejor forma el codigo, por ende tendremos un codigo mas limpio y elegante, ademas de organizado.

Comment: Ahh ya recorde como se llama esa situacion!!!, a la situacion donde el orden si importa, pues algunos elementos pueden no ser reconocidos por el codigo dependiendo del orden, asi que para clarificar un poco mas, diremos que los `prototipos` son `hoisted` debido a que el orden si afecta el producto, mientras que las funciones **NO** son `hoisted` porque no importa el orden en que las tengas estas **siempre van a existir si se encuentran en el mismo contexto**.

Comment: okay, gracias si tengo entendido que eso que estoy haciendo no se hace mas ya que en ES6 se añadieron  algunas cosas que facilita y mejora la forma de hacerlo , gracias por tu buena explicacion y ejemplos.